# Using PDFCreator to create .ps file through IIS

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, iis-7.5

I am converting a .docx, .doc file to .ps file. Work fine on the local machine and prints the .ps file but on IIS 7.5 it doesn't print, I just get this error

"The ActiveX-Server has not been started! Please use function "cStart()" to start the ActiveX-Server!"

I have tried cStart("/NoProcessingAtStartup", false) with no luck and done multiply searches that lead to no resolve. Has anyone run across something like this before?

IIS: 
Anonymous Authorization,
Application Pool Identity

```
PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator creator = new PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator();
PDFCreator.clsPDFCreatorOptions options = new PDFCreator.clsPDFCreatorOptions();
options = creator.cOptions;
PDFCreator.clsPDFCreatorError perr = new PDFCreator.clsPDFCreatorError();

if (!creator.cStart("/NoProcessingAtStartup", false))
{
     Console.Write("Can't Initiase PDF Converter, letter Generation Error");
}

options.UseAutosave = 1;
options.UseAutosaveDirectory = 1;
options.AutosaveDirectory = path;
options.AutosaveFilename = name;
options.AutosaveFormat = 6; //0=PDF, 1=PNG, 2=JPG, 3=BMP, 4=PCX, 5=TIFF, 6=PS, 7= EPS, 8=ASCII
creator.cOptions = options;
creator.cSaveOptions();
creator.cClearCache();
creator.cPrinterStop = false;
creator.cDefaultPrinter = "PDFCreator";
creator.cPrintFile(pathFull);

err = creator.cError.Description.ToString();
```

Comment: If you log on to the server as a new user and try to start PDFCreator interactively does it run through any sort of installer first time use stuff?

Comment: I'm not running PDFCreator on a server, its running on a local machine through IIS for testing. I do get what you're saying, I also think it's a problem with the IIS user that running the program.

Comment: UpDate: It seems it isn't PDFCreator that is the problem it seems it is the access to Word.

Comment: Same rules will apply for Word as I've outlined below for PDFCreator. I'd recommend setting up the DCOM config for it to always run under a specific identity that you know can manually open Word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because the Application Pool User doesn't have permission to run PDFCreator or because it's never run PDFCreator before and on first run it's trying to do some installation or setup interactively and the Application Pool User doesn't have an interactive context. Although I would lean towards the latter as I'd expect a different error if it was the former.

If PDFCreator is accessible via the DCOM config section in Computer Management/Component Services then you could try setting it to always run as under a specific user identity, probably your own.
You would also need to give the Application Pool User permission Launch and Activiation and Access permissions on it.

Alternatively you could try impersonation either in your application config or code and impersonate the account you'd normally use with PDFCreator.

**Update**: Although Word was the actual problem and PDFCreator was trying to activate it, the above suggestions still apply exactly.
If another process is trying to activate Word the user running that process will need to have DCOM permissions on it, and Word will probably need to be run as a specific user if the activating process user doesn't have permission or has never used it before.

As a specific example, say you're running the process under the Network Service account and it tries to activate Word, when a new user tries to run Word for the first time Word will throw up some installation windows for first time configuration, but since the user is not interactively logged in these windows cannot be seen and cannot be responded to so the installation hangs. In this case it is better to set Word to always start up under a specific identity in the DCOM config.

Comment: Yep, we were on the right track finally got it to work after 3 weeks, it was painful but the feeling of ecstasy it well worth the pain!

Comment: Excellent! Any sort of Word automation is usually a total nightmare but once you get the DCOM stuff sorted once it's pretty easy to do for the next time.

Comment: Yea, thanks for the help I definitely got a whole bunch of exp points and leveled up as a programmer today.